# A Real Terminal (Root or No-Root)

Tags: terminal, command-line

I use KUBUNTU on my laptop, but this goes for any Linux distro. I can open a terminal window and type in things like `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get install packagename.` Is there a terminal that can carry out commands like this on Android? It doesn't have to be "sudo", I simply mean carrying out commands. I use the Galaxy S3, but I doubt it really matter for the question I'm asking.

Comment: Did you check the Play Store? There [quite a few](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=terminal&c=apps) [terminal emulators](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=terminal%20emulator&c=app).

Comment: Android does not have the apt package manager

Comment: Yes, but can I do something useful with these emulators with no root? On Ubuntu, you still can.

Comment: Yes, at least [one of them](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Android/Terminal_IDE) supports creating new apps in Java using ssh, rsync, vim, etc. from its terminal command prompt, even if you don't have root.

Comment: You can get `su` and other common GNU commands by rooting your device and installing Busybox (busybox is usually installed while rooting) but you can't get apt since it's a package manager for Debian-based distros. Android is not a linux distro, the only common thing it has  is the linux kernel.

Comment: Termux emulates a full Linux environment, including `apt` as package manager and some interesting utilities.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

<sup>Summing up from the comments:</sup>

First you need to understand that updating apps works different on Android than it does on a "normal" Linux distro: There is no such thing as "apt". Though Android has its own package manager (listening to the `pm` command), installs/updates are *usually* dealt with by services/apps like [google-play-store](/questions/tagged/google-play-store) or other [alternative-markets](/questions/tagged/alternative-markets). `pm` would rather be comparable with [dpkg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dpkg) on Debian-based systems: it can do local installs (i.e. with the `.apk` file already present on the device itself: `pm install` would be the command for that), and a lot of other things.

Apart from that: a terminal app can be compared with a terminal on Linux allright. You get a text-mode "window" where you can execute commands. Most are even similar to those available on Linux, as Android is Linux based: you have things like `cd`, `ls`, `grep`, and more. For details on this, you might wish to take a look at e.g.

- [Ten basic Android terminal commands you should know](http://www.androidcentral.com/android-201-10-basic-terminal-commands-you-should-know) (AndroidCentral)
- [Using the terminal](http://forum.xda-developers.com/wiki/Guide:Using_the_Terminal) (XDA)
- [Android Terminal Commands](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1694251) (XDA)
- [Android Shell Command Reference](https://github.com/jackpal/Android-Terminal-Emulator/wiki/Android-Shell-Command-Reference) (Github)
- our [command-line tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/command-line/info)

A look into our [terminal tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/terminal/info) will not hurt either :)

I'd say all terminal apps available for Android should support the above. Some even offer additional features, such as an entire development environment ([Terminal IDE](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Android/Terminal_IDE)), or access to remote servers ([JuiceSSH](http://www.appbrain.com/app/juicessh-ssh-client/com.sonelli.juicessh)).

Comment: Also worth mentioning, installing busybox adds all the commands "you know and love"

Comment: Right, @saloalv – with the amount of commands depending on the version of Busybox :) Don't forget installing Busybox system-wide usually requires root.

Comment: if it'd be possible to install !system-wide, it'd be great for non-rooted users. Unfortunately it seems that the sdcard partition is fat32, and as such the binary cannot be given execution rights

Comment: @saloalv that's not even the culprit. But it is explicitely mounted with the `noexec` flag (for security reasons).

Answer (score 3):

There **is** a terminal app which uses "apt" to install packages. Its awesome and has lots of packages ported for arm devices -- [Termux](https://termux.com/)  & [Playstore Link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux)

Answer (score 1):

in present days there is the app "termux" on google play store. it comes with a full unix/linux shell and with apt. anything else should be straight forward then. downside: it does not support items like my Android 4.4.2 based tablet.

Answer (score 0):

Install Terminal Emulator and Busybox in your Android. Terminal Emulator gives command-line window and Busybox APK gives useful commands that are used in Linux like `wget`, `chmod`, `chroot` and more.

Comment: Can you link the apps?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that:

1. Your Android device is rooted;
2. The `su` binary is located at `/system/xbin/su`;
3. The shell binary is located at `/system/bin/sh`; and
4. Your Android device has [Terminal Emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm) installed.

If all the 4 conditions above are satisfied, then:

- If you want to enter the shell and become root (superuser uid 0) so you can execute commands without uid restrictions, start the Terminal Emulator app and just execute this command:

  ```
  su -
  ```

  In order to disconnect from the uid 0 (exit superuser status), press <kbd>Volume -</kbd> and <kbd>D</kbd>, or type `exit` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Alternatively, if you want to **always** start Terminal Emulator as root, then start Terminal Emulator, go to **Preferences**, scroll down to the **SHELL** section, tap the **Command line** option and modify the command so it becomes this:

  ```
  /system/xbin/su -c "/system/bin/sh -"
  ```

  After you change the command, exit Terminal Emulator (close the application) and start it again. Notice how Terminal Emulator's shell interface now shows you `root@something` by default.

If you want to add extra commands to your **rooted** Android system, install [BusyBox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=stericson.busybox).

In case your Android device isn't rooted, you still can use Terminal Emulator in order to execute some basic (user) commands such as `blkid`, `cat`, `cd`, `clear`, `cp`, `du`, `grep`, `id`, `ln`, `ls`, `ping`, `sleep`, `uptime` et cetera.

Answer (score -2):

Or you can use [Gnu/Root Debian for android (GPlay)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gnuroot.debian&hl=es)

Comment: Do you always buy the factory if you just want to rent a car?